# Differentiate Integral of x^2

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function. Differentiate :
$$F(x)=\int_0^{x^2} f(x) dx$$
I was thinking of using $\int_a^b f(x)dx= (b-a) f(\theta)$, where $a < \theta < b $, but I don't know neither how to start nor how to finish it

Comment: It is $2xf(x^{2})$ by Chain Rule but do not use $x$ for the variable of integration.

Comment: Use the [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Confusing notation, using $x$ for two different things.  It is better to write $$F(x)=\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt$$

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as $F(x) = G(x^2)$ where $G(t) = \int_{0}^t f(s)ds$. Seeing it this way, you get
$$
F'(x) = 2x G'(x^2) = 2x f(x^2)
$$